# How do i set a field to null in journey builder contact interaction

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

JB supports adding a value to a field, but does not seem to support clearing a value.

Does anyone know what to add to field criteria to clear a value?

Just entering null does not work. It applies the string form of the word null to the field.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried just adding a blank value?

Answer (score 0):

If adding a space doesn't work, just add something like a `.` and then use a query to clear the `.` to NULL.